# Getting the Updated Folder Name(FileLeafRef) in ItemUpdated Event Receiver gives me the wrong name

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, itemupdated

I have an item updated event receiver, when i update a folder name example **"TestName"** to **"TestName Renamed"** the `properties.listItem["FileLeafRef"]` gives me **"TestName"** and not the updated **"TestName Renamed"** do you know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: try checking the value in properties.AfterProperties collection instead of properties.ListItem

Comment: @DamjanTomic the after properties doesn't have any value. as of now what im doing is getting the afterUrl to get the updated folder name